# Django group by and count

Tags: python, django

I am trying to perform a grouping on my model which looks like this:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    pass

class Order(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant')
```

Now I want to know how many orders were created each day. This means I need to get date from DateTime field and then a count.

If it's relevant, I'm getting `Order` queryset in this way:

```
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=request.data['restaurant_id'])
orders = restaurant.order_set.filter(created__lte=some_date)
```

Now, how can I get what I want from `orders`? I have tried things like:

```
orders.values('created').annotate(Count('created'))
```

Using `TruncDate` and so on.

I am using Python 2 and Django 1.11.

**EDIT** To better express my intentions. I want something that I would achieve in pure python with something like this:

```
orders_by_date = {}
for order in orders:
    if orders_by_date.get(datetime.date(orders[0].created.year, orders[0].created.month, orders[0].created.day):
        orders_by_date[datetime.date(orders[0].created.year, orders[0].created.month, orders[0].created.day)] += 1
    else:
        orders_by_date[datetime.date(orders[0].created.year, orders[0].created.month, orders[0].created.day)] = 1
```

**EDIT2** I was able to successfully display count for a single date:

```
orders.filter(created__date=datetime.date(2018, 6, 8)).aggregate(Count('id'))
```

Gave me `{'id__count': 3}`. Now It would be perfect to group by all dates, not just this single one.

Comment: When you say group by all dates, do you mean get `id__count` for each date?

Comment: More or less yes. To be precise: if I have 1 order created on 1.1.2018 at 12:00, second created on 1.1.2018 on 13:00, third created on 2.1.2018 at 12:00, I'd expect an output similar to `{date(2018, 1, 1): 2, date(2018, 1, 2): 1}`. If it's `{'id__count': 2, 'created_date': date(2018, 1, 1), (...)` I'm fine with it.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the data in one query with:

```
from django.db.models import DateField, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

query = Order.objects.filter(
    restaurant=some_restaurant
).annotate(
    create_date=Cast('created', DateField())
).values('create_date').annotate(
    id_count=Count('id')
).order_by('create_date')
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of dictionaries like:

```
<QuerySet [{'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 31), 'id_count': 14}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 2), 'id_count': 25}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 9), 'id_count': 13},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 10), 'id_count': 2}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 16), 'id_count': 17},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 17), 'id_count': 89}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 20), 'id_count': 20},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 23), 'id_count': 18}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 24), 'id_count': 20},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 2, 28), 'id_count': 20}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1), 'id_count': 3},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 3), 'id_count': 9}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 7), 'id_count': 9},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 'id_count': 1}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 'id_count': 7}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 14), 'id_count': 2}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 15), 'id_count': 7},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 17), 'id_count': 9}, 
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 22), 'id_count': 2},
           {'create_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 24), 'id_count': 8},
           '...
           (remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

(added formatting)

Behind the curtains, it will generate a query like:

```
SELECT CAST(`order`.`created` AS date) AS `create_date`,
       COUNT(`order`.`id`) AS `id_count`
FROM `order`
WHERE `order`.`restaurant_id` = 123
GROUP BY CAST(`order`.`created` AS date)
ORDER BY `create_date` ASC
```

(where `123` is here a sample restaurant id).

So you can then for instance iterate over the result and construct a JSON object, etc.

We can for example translate it into a dictionary that maps `datetime.date` objects to counts by iterating over the query with *dictionary comprehension*:

```
result = { t['create_date']: t['id_count'] for t in query }
```

Note that dates without any `Order` will not be part of the queryset (nor of the `result` dictionary, this is logical, since we take the `Order` table as "root", and if there are no rows, then there will be no output)

Comment: This solved my problem. Incase anyone was interested in what query is created I'm pasting it here: `In [57]: print(x.query)
SELECT "papu_order"."created"::date AS "create_date", COUNT("papu_order"."id") AS "id_count" FROM "papu_order" WHERE "papu_order"."restaurant_id" = 1 GROUP BY "papu_order"."created"::date ORDER BY "create_date" ASC
`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do `orders.filter(created__date=datetime.date(2018, 6, 8)).values('id__count')`, which would give you a list of dictionaries: `[{'id__count': 3},{'id__count': 1},...]`.

Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#)

---

Edit:
Try annotating then getting the values:

```
orders_with_counts = orders.annotate(Count('id'))
dates_and_counts = orders_with_counts.values_list('created__date','id__count')
dct = dict(dates_and_counts)
```

`dates_and_counts` would be a list of tuples: `[(date1,count1),(date2,count2)...]`. `dct` would be that converted to a dictionary.

Comment: It gives me `{FieldError}Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field. Join on 'id' not permitted.` And still it doesn't solve the grouping problem. I'd like to do it on database if possible, not in python.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted that part. What results do you want from grouping by dates?

Comment: As I've said I'd like pairs of date-count. So if I have 1 order created on 1.1.2018 at 12:00, second created on 1.1.2018 on 13:00, third created on 2.1.2018 at 12:00, I'd expect an output similar to `{date(2018, 1, 1): 2, date(2018, 1, 2): 1}`